# Could China's actions in Xinjiang be classified as genocide?

Tags: china, genocide, uyghurs

According to [some articles](https://foreignpolicy.com/2020/07/15/uighur-genocide-xinjiang-china-surveillance-sterilization/), China is carrying out genocide against the Uyghur people. Others claim it is [cultural genocide](https://www.dw.com/en/opinion-beijings-cultural-genocide-in-xinjiang/a-51407530) as its the Uyghur culture that is being eliminated, rather than Uyghurs as a nation. So which one is correct? Is it "genocide", "cultural genocide", neither, or both?

Comment: I really dislike questions of the style *could X be classified/considered as Y?* At the very least, the question should clarify the defintions to be used, but *could* sounds very vague as well. A better question might be *are relevant authorities classifying X as Y and which authorities can be considered relevant?*

Comment: If the definitions were clear cut, that would remove the need to ask in the first place.

Comment: Well, how come? Shall we mention standard examples like the Holocaust? There are surviving Jews, of course, still I don't think anybody would question whether it was genocide.

Comment: From your last sentence, the option [ethnocide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethnocide) is missing.

Comment: @Gábor [There are still people who deny it.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holocaust_denial) Naturally, there are all kinds of genocide that can be denied, like the [Armenian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armenian_Genocide), [Rwandan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rwandan_genocide) and many others. Just because most people agree on something, doesn't mean all people agree on something. Even acknowledging there was an Armenian genocide is a very sensitive matter in Turkey. So yes, [people deny that too](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armenian_Genocide_denial).

Comment: @gerrit: "Some ethnologists, such as Robert Jaulin, use the term "ethnocide" as a substitute for "cultural genocide" " -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_genocide

Answer (score 61):

### Genocide Defined

The [Convention on the Prevention and Punishment of the Crime of Genocide](https://www.un.org/en/genocideprevention/documents/atrocity-crimes/Doc.1_Convention%20on%20the%20Prevention%20and%20Punishment%20of%20the%20Crime%20of%20Genocide.pdf) (the international law defining the crime of genocide) says that genocide is:

> In the present Convention, genocide means any of the following acts committed with
> intent to destroy, in whole or in part, a national, ethnical, racial or religious group, as
> such:
>
> (a) Killing members of the group;
>
> (b) Causing serious bodily or mental harm to members of the group;
>
> (c) Deliberately inflicting on the group conditions of life calculated to bring about its
> physical destruction in whole or in part;
>
> (d) Imposing measures intended to prevent births within the group;
>
> (e) Forcibly transferring children of the group to another group.

### China has imposed measure to prevent Uyghur births

China has implemented policies designed to prevent Uyghurs from having children, a definition which satisfies item (d) of the definition of genocide. Adrian Zenz, an academic specializing in Chinese politics, authored [this document](https://jamestown.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Zenz-Sterilizations-IUDs-and-Mandatory-Birth-Control-FINAL-27June.pdf?x62792) which argues that China's use of forced sterilizations and IUDs for Uyghurs satisfies the legal criterion for genocide. Breaking these birth control laws is punishable by being sent to internment camps. There are also many news outlets online which describe these sterilizations and IUDs, such as [this one](https://www.heritage.org/asia/commentary/chinas-forced-sterilization-uighur-women-cultural-genocide).

This policy differs from China's more general "[one child"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-child_policy#cite_note-3) policy.
Although it uses a case study focusing on Koreans in China, [this academic article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1966715?origin=crossref&seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) explains that ethnic minorities were allowed more children. It seems that in many cases the limit was not enforced at all.

Unexpectedly, when the State [increased the limit](https://web.archive.org/web/20171010151510/http://news.xinhuanet.com/english/2015-12/27/c_134955448.htm) to 2 children per couple nation-wide in 2015, the birth rate for Uyghurs decreased by 84% (Zenz, ibid). Why did it decrease? Zenz ([and others](https://www.latimes.com/world-nation/story/2020-06-28/china-forces-birth-control-on-uighurs-to-suppress-population)) report that enforcement is different. While any ethnicity is theoretically able to be forced to have an IUD, sterilization, or fined, the this punishment is largely saved for ethnic minorities like the Uyghur. Internment camps also appear to be unique for ethnic minorities, which also indicates unequal enforcement in a pretty dramatic way. Internment camps are also used to house family and acquaintances of Uyghurs who do not follow these laws.

An additional tactic reported by Business Insider: when a man is taken to an internment camp, the Chinese government [may assign Chinese men](https://www.businessinsider.com/china-uighur-monitor-home-shared-bed-report-2019-11) to sleep with his wife and live in his house with his family. Although not related to IUD or sterilization, this is another unique policing tactic that is applied unequally to Uyghurs and the ethnic majority.

### Other Stories

Outside of the legal argument, there are extant claims that China is systematically killing Uyghurs. I'm presenting this anecdotal evidence because I believe that often first hand accounts are important and under utilized on this site, but also because Uyghurs are an ethnic group that are not commonly encountered in the United States (and I suspect, other western countries).

While at the University of Kansas, I studied Uyghur language where I came to know several Uyghurs from Xinjiang, as well as an extended network of scholars interested in the politics of Xinjiang.

Several of the indigenous Uyghur acquaintances I made have never been heard from since. My instructor, as well as their family and friends, shared their own personal stories of "missing" loved ones, some of which have been missing for a decade or more. In particular, I knew [Abduweli Ayup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abduweli_Ayup), who was a linguistics student at the time.

Though I can't vouch for the scale of deaths caused by these policies, but this information and my experience with these people supports definition (C). These disappearances are intended to destroy Uyghur people "in whole or in part".

Comment: Given that the Chinese government imposed birth control measures in the rest of the country too, did they commit genocide against the Han people?

Comment: @JonathanReez I'm not knowledgeable in the details of their more general policy. If the rules are the same nation wide, and they are enforced similarly nation wide, I would think probably not. I'll see if I can find if there is a difference here.

Comment: @JonathanReez Updated. See the later part of the section about births.

Comment: @JonathanReez the intent wasn't to destroy

Comment: @Fattie Thanks. You too can study Uyghur from the comfort of your own home. Our instructors published their own textbook as a PDF available for free. Downside: they are linguists, and it shows. https://kuscholarworks.ku.edu/bitstream/handle/1808/5624/EngYakDwy2010_Uyg1full_11.pdf?sequence=13&isAllowed=y

Comment: This answer mentions the government *may assign Chinese men to sleep with his wife*, but this is not exactly backed up by the Business Insider article, at least not in what "to sleep with" generally means in English.  By this choice of words, it sounds like state-sanctioned rape, however the article describes it differently.  The state lies, of course. In reality we don't know if those "visits" regularly and intentionally result in women becoming pregnant, or if it's "just" a deeply privacy-invasive control/intimidation measure. Your phrasing could communicate this uncertainty somewhat better.

Comment: @gerrit The quote from one of the officials sure said rape doesn't happen. I definitely read the entire article as about state sanctioned rape.

Comment: @indigochild The homestays have frequently led to coerced marriages between the Han "guests" and Uyghur women in the community, which could likely constitute further genocidal limitation of in-group births. However, the sleeping arrangements of the homestays themselves don't amount to state-sanctioned rape, except possibly by negligence. Important context is that it is common for a whole household to sleep on a single heated platform (sometimes misleadingly described as the same bed). While we could infer that this may lead to abuses given the power imbalance between guest and host,

Comment: there isn't really direct evidence of this. It's fairly clear that the coerced marriages are the larger issue. https://supchina.com/2019/08/07/uyghur-love-in-a-time-of-interethnic-marriage/

Comment: The issue with this answer is it relies on just two kinds of sources: Adrian Zenz (who is funded directly by the US state for the explicit purpose of publishing anti-communist articles), and individual anecdotes (that are mostly shared via an org set up by the CIA, and whose explicit purpose of publishing anti-Chinese information). More complete information from less biased sources would be a big help.

Comment: @JonathanReez: the confusion is that while China *had* a one-child policy for everyone, which was poorly enforced against the mostly rural Uighurs, but better enforced again the urban populations (the fines [were](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/99870/if-someone-received-the-minimum-subsistence-guarantee-in-china-but-were-fined-f) much higher for the latter, for starters) there's now the opposite situation. https://www.vox.com/future-perfect/22311356/china-uyghur-birthrate-sterilization-genocide

Comment: @JonathanReez: and while 'genocide' is a [actually a vaguely defined term](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/84566/18373), [there are](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/84865/18373) treaties that explicitly prohibit the forcible limiting of  births in practically all circumstances. But China hasn't signed up to those treaties, of course. But 'suck for them', they did sign up to one that makes it illegal to limit births on ethnic grounds .

Answer (score 27):

China is actively terminating the future of an ethnic minority:

> The Chinese government is taking draconian measures to slash birth rates among Uighurs and other minorities as part of a sweeping campaign to curb its Muslim population, even as it encourages some of the country’s Han majority to have more children.
>
> While individual women have spoken out before about forced birth control, the practice is far more widespread and systematic than previously known, according to an AP investigation based on government statistics, state documents and interviews with 30 ex-detainees, family members and a former detention camp instructor. The campaign over the past four years in the far west region of Xinjiang is leading to what some experts are calling a form of “demographic genocide.”
>
> The state regularly subjects minority women to pregnancy checks, and forces intrauterine devices, sterilization and even abortion on hundreds of thousands, the interviews and data show. Even while the use of IUDs and sterilization has fallen nationwide, it is rising sharply in Xinjiang.

[source](https://apnews.com/269b3de1af34e17c1941a514f78d764c)

While the above is not mass murder, this is still genocide: ["the deliberate and systematic destruction of a racial, political, or cultural group"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/genocide).

Separate but concurrently, China is also systematically assimilating that culture, what is referenced as "cultural genocide" (as per the DW article in the question).

So the answer to the question is both genocide and cultural genocide. But do note that saying "both" implies a kind of equality for both actions, which is wrong.

Comment: How is "cultural genocide" different from ethnocide?

Comment: @gerrit: Definitions vary; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethnocide.

Comment: @gerrit If you see one, the other is likely to follow. ;)